# Edit/Update IsolatedStorageFileStream XML File

Tags: c#, xml, isolatedstorage

### Problem

---

I have a XML file in Isolated Storage and I need to edit the file and remove all the occurrences of the "Time" node inside the file. The file needs to then update.

### Code

---

This is the section of the code that is opening the XML file in Isolated Storage:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream doc = localStorage.OpenFile(xmlFile, FileMode.Open))
{

}
```

I have attempted to use XDocument to remove all the "Time" nodes but this didn't seem to work so I just need a way of removing the node from "doc".

### EDIT

---

This code has been added which adds the new XML to the file but when i view the file in local stoage it is empty?

```
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream doc = localStorage.OpenFile(xmlFile, FileMode.Open))
            {

                System.Xml.Linq.XDocument test = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(doc);
                test.Declaration.Version = "1.0";
                test.Declaration.Encoding = "utf-16";
                test.Declaration.Standalone = "yes";

                test.Descendants("Time").Remove();
                doc.Position = 0;
                test.Save(doc);

                XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(doc);
                if (location.GetType() == typeof(PortableBusinessObjects.Shape))
                    _xmlShapeSerializer.Serialize(writer, location);
                else if (location.GetType() == typeof(PortableBusinessObjects.Point))
                    _xmlPointSerializer.Serialize(writer, location);




                doc.Flush();
                doc.Close();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the XDocument, did you save it back to the stream (method `Save()`)? Because otherwise, nothign is going to happen, I think.

Comment: Yes, i saved it back but It added it to the file meaning it duplicated the contents.

Comment: That at least proves that you can write to the stream. But after reading the entire XML, the stream pointer is at the end of the stream, and further writing will append your data to the existing XML. If your stream supports seeking (check property `CanSeek`), then try setting the `Position` property to 0. I'm not sure what happens, though, when the new XML is shorter than the old XML.

Comment: Yes, I have set the position now which has successfully overwritten the XML and does not include time. The problem is now the file in Local Storage does not contain anything